# Display netCDF files to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, netcdf

I have some meteorological data wich are exported to `netCDF` format and I want to display them in Google Maps.

I tried the Panoply software, mainly following these http://marinedataliteracy.org/ops/pano_gridsvecs.htm instructions and succesfully exported the data into `.kml` files.

The kml file displays fine in Google Earth, but when loading it in Google Maps nothing is being displayed.

The JavaScript code that is loading the kml is definitely correct, because other types of kml are displayed correctly. Just in case, this is the code:

```
var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer("LINK_TO_KML");
kmzLayer.setMap(map);
```

There is also a project called `netcdf2gmaps` here http://code.google.com/p/netcdf2gmaps/ but it seems abandoned and there is no feedback for it.

So is there any way to display the netCDF data to Google Maps?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you solved your problem, but for reference to question title I thought to add more info.

Panoply (or IDV) export to KMZ (zipped KML) in a manner of simple PNG snapshot of their current display and lon/lat boundaries, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
    <GroundOverlay>
        <name>Maximum_temperature_Maximum_unwe in GEFS_Global_1p0deg_Ensemble_deri</name>
        <Icon>
            <href>Maximum_temperature_Maximum_unwe in GEFS_Global_1p0deg_Ensemble_deri.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <LatLonBox>
            <west>-29.1622</west>
            <north>55.0</north>
            <east>49.1622</east>
            <south>25.0</south>
        </LatLonBox>
    </GroundOverlay>
</kml>
```

And that seems like only way to Google Earth interface - bitmap images. Which is a sad fact that Google Earth is not designed for visualization or numerical model data, as it can't represent varaious other features.

If overlaying bitmap in Google Earth/Maps is the task than as you have already noticed it's just a matter of double clicking produced KMZ file:

[image]

or for Google Maps, uploading the file and pasting the path in Google Maps search bar:

[image]

Comment: No i havent found a solution yet.
Also my problem is that the KMZ file is not displayed at Google Maps.
It just shows a infowindow with the name of the file but the overlay image is not displayed at all.
My KML file has the same structure as yours.

Comment: Isn't uploading KMZ file and pasting the path in Google Maps an option for you? I'm not sure, but AFAIK this works for all kinds or URLs except for local files (with "file://" prefix)

Comment: Yes it is working for any other kind of KMZ i upload to my online server(not local), but if it has an image it is not displayed.